# Cycle2 not running

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need to run a slideshow using cycle2 for images from a particular folder. Below is my markup and php:

```
<div class="cycleShow">
    <?php
        $dir = 'img/';
        $files = scandir($dir);
        foreach($files as $file) {
            if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
                $tag = '<img class="thumbNail" src="' . $dir . $file . '" />';
                echo $tag;
            }
        }
    ?>
</div>

<button onClick="slideshow();">Start</button>
```

and the function.....

```
    function slideshow() {
        $('.cycleShow').cycle();
    }
```

When executed, the images loads into the div. but no slideshow on click of button.

Comment: have you checked for any js erros in developer tools?

Comment: shouldn't it be `onclick="..."` ?

Comment: no js errors, nothing.

Answer (score 1):

your class for the div is incorrect it should be `class='cycle-slideshow'`.

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem